# Git Personal Access Token works with Eclipse but not in Git Bash

Tags: git, github

I have a Git repository that I have configured to work with Eclipse.  When I try to push to the repo from Eclipse, I give it my username and a Personal Access Token generated from GitHub, and it can push fine.

When I use this same username/personal acess token combination from Git Bash, I can fetch and pull but not push.  I get a "403" error saying "Invalid username/password."

Why does this combination work from within Eclipse but not from Git Bash?

Comment: You must have made a mistake in providing the token to 'Git Bash'... What you mean by the latter exactly? Do you mean 'git' on the command line?

Comment: The token works when I run fetch/pull, I just can't push from Git Bash.  And yes, I mean the command line when I say Git Bash.  I can push fine from Eclipse, but not from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching/pulling is read-only, you don't need a token for that. A token is used to interact with the GitHub API, not to push something to your repository.

To be able to push something, your need to make sure you're using the right password (if you're pushing via HTTPS) or SSH public key (if you're pushing via `git://`). You probably have this configured in Eclipse somewhere.

Comment: I understand that fetching/pulling is read-only, although Git Bash still prompts you for a token when you run those commands.  I ran a test and from Eclipse, the exact same token works when doing a push.  But that token from Git Bash doesn't work for pushing.  I get a "403" error.

Comment: BTW, I am doing everything via HTTPS.

Comment: One more comment and then I'll stop: I also just tried doing a command line pull and, when prompted for my username and password, I gave it nonsense for the password, and the pull failed.  So obviously it is doing something with the authentication for the pull, and the token works with pulling, but something is going haywire with pushing.

Comment: You're mixing up a token and a simple password.